# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Boardapi_update is missing a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Boardapi_update is missing a QuerySet. Define Boardapi_update.model, Boardapi_update.queryset, or override Boardapi_update.get_queryset().

This error occurs. The same error occurred with boardapi_delete.

help me!!!!!!!!!!!

views.py

```
class Boardapi_update(generic.UpdateView):
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = {
            'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
        }

        data = {
            'b_title': requests.POST.get['b_title'],
            'b_note': requests.POST.get['b_note']
        }

        url = 'http://localhost:8080/boardapi/'+str(pk['pk'])+'/update/'

        bupdate = requests.put(url, data=data)
    
        print(bupdate)

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.board.pk})


class Boardapi_delete(generic.DeleteView):
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        datas = {
            'pk': self.kwargs['pk']
        }

        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/boardapi/'+str(datas['pk'])+'/delete/'

        bdelete = requests.delete(url, params=datas)

        print(bdelete)
       
        return redirect(reverse('board'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not good. If you want to write with your this method, Then, delete
**generic.UpdateView**. Why? because **generic.UpdateView** requires  its own methodology.

For ex:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form' 


from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-list')
```

You can read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ more about.

**Tips**: Always do research for a short time, then start coding.

Comment: I'm not good at English. I don't know exactly. Can you tell me what to do? I will analyze and study based on what you told me.